# Generate auto build and upload to ftp server using bitbucket pipelines

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have been trying to generate the build using bitbucket pipelines and upload it to my FTP server.
But every time I try to run the pipeline, I get this error.

*git ftp init --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST_PATHfatal: Can't access remote 'ftp://ubuntu:***@mywebsite.com', exiting...*

My whole pipeline script looks like this

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git
pipelines: 
default: 
    - step: 
      caches:
    - composer 
      script: 
           - apt-get update
           - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
           - git ftp init --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD sftp://$SFTP_HOST:22/$SFTP_FOLDER
```

Answer (score 0):

used Rsync instead of git-FTP and it worked fine.